# Does $(7,3,6,7)$ occur in the infinite sequence $(1,9,9,3,...)$ in which every component is the unit digit of the sum of its $4$ preceding components?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'll appreciate solution hints for the following question from a past exam in Discrete Mathematics that was administered in my university.

Denote by $\mathbb{N}$ the set of positive integers. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ denote by $n\%10$ the remainder of the division of $n$ by $10$, i.e. $n%10$ is the unique number satisfying:
$$
\begin{align}
n\%10&\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\},\\
n-(n\%10)&=0\mod10.
\end{align}
$$

We postulate that the infinite sequence $n = (n_1, n_2, \dots)$ satisfies:
$$
\begin{align}
n_1 &= 1,\\
n_2 &= 9,\\
n_3 &= 9,\\ 
n_4 &= 3,
\end{align}
$$
and for every $i\in\mathbb{N}_1$ $n_{i+4}$ is the unit digit in the decimal representation of the sum of the preceding $4$ components of $n$: $n_{i+4}=(n_i+n_{i+1}+n_{i+2}+n_{i+3})\%10$.

Is there some $i_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the following four equations hold?
$$
\begin{align}
n_{i_0}&=7,\\
n_{i_0+1}&=3,\\
n_{i_0+2}&=6,\\
n_{i_0+3}&=7.
\end{align}
$$

---

**My attempts to solve the question**

I computed $n_1$ to $n_{45}$:
$$
\begin{align}
n':=(&1,9,9,3,2,3,7,5,7,\\
&2,1,5,5,3,4,7,9,3,\\
&3,2,7,5,7,1,0,3,1,\\
&5,9,8,3,5,5,1,4,5,\\
&5,5,9,4,3,1,7,5,6),
\end{align}
$$
and I extended the sequence $(7,3,6,7)$ "backwards" to a total of 27 components:
$$
\begin{align}
m:=(&4,3,9,5,1,8,3,7,9,\\
&7,6,9,1,3,9,2,5,9,\\
&5,1,0,5,1,7,3,6,7).
\end{align}
$$

I was hoping this would enable me to solve the question by one of the following ways.

1. If it turned out that for some $i\in\{1,2,\dots,42\}$ $n'_i=m_1=4$, $n'_{i+1}=m_2=3$, $n'_{i+2}=m_3=9$, $n'_{i+3}=m_4=5$, then the answer to the original question would be: yes. However, this is not the case.
2. If I could identify a repeating pattern in $n'$ which didn't manifest in $m$, or vice versa, then the answer to the original question might be: no. However, I was unable to identify such patterns.
3. If I could show that one of the digits $0, 1, \dots, 9$ didn't occur in $n'$, but occurred in $m$, or vice versa, then the answer to the original question might be: no. However, all the digits occur in both $n'$ and $m$.
4. If I were able to prove that every possible quadruple $(a,b,c,d)\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}^4$ eventually occurs in either $(n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots)$ or $(\dots,m_{25},m_{26},m_{27})$ (the infinite extension of $m$ "backwards"), then the answer to the original question would be: yes. However, I wasn't able to prove this.

Comment: No need to [reinvent the wheel (permutation cycle).](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4810/242) You can (uniquely) iterate backwards (since shifting is invertible mod $10$) so
the orbits are *cycles*, as explained in the link. That $7,3,6,7$ lies in the initial cycle follows quickly by extending it forward, as mentioned below. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20wheel%20cycle&searchOn=3) for many examples of this sort. Once you know the simple idea it is easy to solve them all.

Comment: In case you're curious; the smallest positive integer $i$ such that $(n_i,n_{i+1},n_{i+2},n_{i+3})=(7,6,3,7)$ is $i=1553$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try searching forward from $7,3,6,7$. (You don't have to go very far at all before something interesting happens.)

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of extending $7,3,6,7$ *forward*. I've extended it forward, and discovered the beginning of the first sequence: $1,9,9,3$. This implies that if $7,3,6,7,$ occurs in the sequence beginning with $1,9,9,3$, then the latter is a cyclic sequence. Now what?

Comment: a) Try to prove that your sequence must be cyclic (not using the hint). b) Think about how if you know $n_k, n_{k+1}, n_{k+2}, n_{k+3}$ you can calculate $n_{k-1}$

Comment: Backing up is unique.