# $p^t$ divides $C(n,p^r)$, $p^{t+1}$ doesn't

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I'm having trouble seeing why this (it's stated as obvious in a proof of Sylow's first theorem): if $n=mp^r$ ($p$ is prime), and $p^t\mid m$ but $p^{t+1}\nmid m$, then $p^t\mid\binom{n}{p^r}$ but $p^{t+1}\nmid\binom{n}{p^r}$.

I also wonder if a combinatorial proof of this fact can be given.

Thank you in advance for any help given.

Comment: I have added the combinatorics tag because you are looking for a combinatorial proof.

Comment: @Chandru1: no problem. I hadn't done it because I thought somebody would reply to the combinatorial proof question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same idea which *I.N.Herstein* uses to prove the First Sylow theorem. So i would recommend you to have a peep into his, *Topics in Algebra* book, Sec **2.12,** Group Theory, **Page 92**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

If we expand ${ mp^r \choose p^r }$ in the usual way we obtain

$${ mp^r \choose p^r } = m \prod_{k=1}^{p^r-1} \frac{mp^r-k}{p^r-k}$$

and since $mp^r -k= (m-1)p^r + (p^r-k)$ the power of $p$ dividing $mp^r-k$ is the same as the power of $p$ dividing $p^r-k.$ Hence the powers of $p$ in the numerator and denominator of the above product cancel, which gives us the result due to the $m$ before the product sign.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this follows easily by *aligning* the numerator and denominator factors modulo $\rm\ p^r \ $ in order to obtain maximal cancellation of powers of $\rm\:p\:.\:$ This is a special case of the simple arithmetical method I described in my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/division-of-factorials/2192#2192) to prove that binomial coefficients are integers. See also this very [simple example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/proving-n-choose-p-equiv-bigl-fracnp-bigr-textmod-p/5829#5829) for motivation. I think that you'll find that the key conceptual idea is clearer after studying these further examples.