# Prove the following :

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

Prove the following :
$$
{{n}\choose{7}}-\left \lfloor{\frac{n}{7}}\right \rfloor 
$$
is divisible by 7.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/proving-n-choose-p-equiv-bigl-fracnp-bigr-textmod-p