# The relationship between Legendre Polynomials and monomial basis polynomials

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I am currently doing filter designs and stumbled across this mathematical problem which I cannot understand. I was hoping for some insight from experts around this field to help me with this.

$$\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\ h_{m}\ x^{m} = \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\ g_{m}\ P_{m}\left(x\right)$$

where 
$P_{m}\left(x\right)$ is the Legendre polynomials and $x^{m}$ is the conventional polynomials.

I want to know the relationship between $g_{m}$ and $h_{m}$, what is the best approach? Is there a closed form solution for $h_{m}$?

Thanks in advance, and apologies if it is a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might as well: there is an algorithm, due to [Salzer](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/355611.362548), for converting to and from different orthogonal polynomial expansions. (I previously talked about this algorithm [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40184).) If you intend to do this entire business of conversions, I believe an algorithm might be more useful to you than an integral expression.

What follows are a few relevant *Mathematica* routines. Even though I used *Mathematica*, I hope that the algorithm is still transparent and easily translatable (the indexing starts from 1; some adjustment is necessary if the indexing in your language starts at 0):

```
monomialToLegendre[pc_?VectorQ] := 
 Module[{n = Length[pc] - 1, lc, q},
  lc[1] = pc[[n]]; lc[2] = Last[pc];
  Do[
   q[1] = lc[1];
   lc[1] = pc[[n - k + 1]] + lc[2]/3;
   Do[
    q[j] = lc[j];
    lc[j] = j lc[j + 1]/(2 j + 1) + (j - 1) q[j - 1]/(2 j - 3);
    , {j, 2, k - 1}];
   q[k] = lc[k];
   lc[k] = (k - 1) q[k - 1]/(2 k - 3);
   lc[k + 1] = k q[k]/(2 k - 1);
   , {k, 2, n}];
  Table[lc[k], {k, n + 1}]]
```

One could use Salzer again for converting from the Legendre to the monomial basis. However, it is a bit clearer (and gives rise to essentially the same method) to treat the problem as one of Taylor/Maclaurin expansion of the polynomial expressed in terms of Legendre polynomials. One can then use [Clenshaw's algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1965-0172445-6) for the purpose:

```
legendreToMonomial[lc_?VectorQ] := 
 Module[{n = Length[lc] - 1, pc, v = 0, w, z},
  pc[1] = Last[lc]; pc[_] = z[_] = 0;
  Do[
   w = pc[1];
   pc[1] = lc[[j]] - v z[1];
   z[1] = w;
   Do[
    w = pc[i];
    pc[i] = (2 j - 1) z[i - 1]/j - v z[i];
    z[i] = w;
    , {i, 2, n - j + 2}];
   v = (j - 1)/j;
   , {j, n, 1, -1}];
  Table[pc[j], {j, n + 1}]]
```

As an example, to demonstrate the identity

$$5P_0(x)-4P_1(x)-2P_2(x)+3P_3(x)+P_4(x)=\frac{35}{8}x^4+\frac{15}{2}x^3-\frac{27}{4}x^2-\frac{17}{2}x+\frac{51}{8}$$

```
monomialToLegendre[legendreToMonomial[{5, -4, -2, 3, 1}]] ==
 {5, -4, -2, 3, 1}
True

legendreToMonomial[monomialToLegendre[{51/8, -17/2, -27/4, 15/2, 35/8}]] 
 == {51/8, -17/2, -27/4, 15/2, 35/8}
True
```

Comment: You are a champ J.M.! Good to see it works, I will follow some of your recommended readings and see if I can understand a bit. Since I am using Matlab instead of Mathematica, I am having a hard time understanding your equations used to do the conversion =(

Comment: MATLAB supports loops, so it shouldn't be too hard. The indexed variables should be turned into proper arrays in MATLAB, of the same dimensions as the array of coefficients.

Comment: R code for anyone more familiar with C-like syntax implementing these equations may be found here https://github.com/NathanWycoff/GenInterpConv/blob/master/R/legendre.R

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your domain is $(-1,1)$ else you would need to do some rescaling of the following argument. The main thing to exploit is that the Legendre polynomials are orthogonal i.e. $$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} P_m(x) P_n(x) = \frac{2}{2n+1} \delta_{mn}.$$ Using this we get that $$g_n = \left(\frac{2n+1}{2} \right) \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} \left( h_m \int_{-1}^{1} x^m P_n(x) \right)$$

Comment: Yes sir, the domain had been rescaled to [-1, 1] and thank you for the closed form expression! Much much appreciated. Just wondering will it be possible to revert the expression around to get $h_{m}$ instead? Sorry my maths is quite lacking.