# Monomials in terms of Legendre polynomials

Tags: polynomials, special-functions, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Is there a closed-form expression for a monomial $x^m$ in terms of a sum of [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) $P_n(x)$?

$$ x^m = \sum_n a_n P_n(x) $$

How can I determine the coefficients $a_n$ in general?

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86298/the-relationship-between-legendre-polynomials-and-monomial-basis-polynomials?rq=1) question (and [here](http://www.physics.fudan.edu.cn/chinese/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=people:kevin:lf0706.pdf)), the answer seems to be something along the lines of

$$ a_n = \frac{2n + 1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 x^m P_n(x) \,\mathrm{d}x $$

How can I use orthogonality to prove this? Can the integral be expressed in closed form?

Comment: Multiply with $P_k(x)$ to get $x^m P_k(x) = \sum_n a_n P_n(x) P_k(x)$. Now integrate over $[-1,1]$ and notice that the only non-zero term on the right hand side is for $n=k$ (this is beacuse of the orthogonality relation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start from the definition of [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) through its generating function:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tx+t^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x) t^n$$

Introduce variable $s$ such that

$$1 - ts = \sqrt{1-2tx + t^2} 
\iff x = \frac{1+t^2 - (1-ts)^2}{2t} = s + \frac{t}{2}(1-s^2)
$$
We have $\displaystyle\;\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-2tx+t^2}} = \frac{1+t(-s)}{1-ts} ds = ds\;$ and hence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \int_{-1}^1 x^m P_n(x) dx
= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^m dx}{\sqrt{1-2tx+t^2}} 
= \int_{-1}^1 \left(s + \frac{t}{2}(1-s^2)\right)^m ds
$$
By comparing the coefficients of $t^n$ on both sides, we find the coefficients defined by
$$a_{m,n} \stackrel{def}{=} \int_{-1}^1 x^m P_n(x) dx$$
vanishes whenever $n > m$ and $m, n$ has different parity. When $n = m - 2k$ for some integer $k$, we have

$$\begin{align}
a_{m,m-2k} 
&= 2^{2k-m}\binom{m}{2k}\int_{-1}^1 s^{2k} (1-s^2)^{m-2k} ds
= 2^{2k-m}\binom{m}{2k}\int_0^1 y^{k-\frac12} (1-y)^{m-2k} dy\\
&= 2^{2k-m}\binom{m}{2k}\frac{\Gamma(k+\frac12)\Gamma(m-2k+1)}{\Gamma(m-k+\frac32)}
= \frac{m!}{2^{k-1}k!(2m-2k+1)!!}
\end{align}
$$
Together with the orthogonality relation
$$\frac{2\ell+1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} P_\ell(x) P_\ell'(x) = \begin{cases}1,& \ell = \ell'\\0, & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

We find for integer $m$,

$$x^m = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor} \left(\frac{2m-4k+1}{2}\right) a_{m,m-2k} P_{m-2k}(x)
= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\frac{m!(2m-4k+1)}{2^k k!(2m-2k+1)!!}P_{m-2k}(x)
$$