# A question on algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $$a+{1\over b}=b+{1\over c}=c+{1\over a}=p$$
$a,b,c$ are distinct real numbers
What is the value of $p$ in terms of $a,b,c$?

1. $abc$
2. $-abc$
3. $a+b+c$
4. $ab+bc+ca$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: a+(1/b) this type

Comment: You can test each candidate solution.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Any of these three already give $p$ in terms of $a,b,c$.

Comment: One of those is indeed correct, though $p=1$ would be rather simpler

Comment: @Henry I object. $p=\color{red}{\pm}1$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin fair enough

Comment: Multiply these equations with each other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a,b,c are three distinct real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1024058/631742)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61054/if-a-1-b-b-1-c-c-1-a-how-to-find-the-value-of-abc

Comment: It is a correct question see $abc+p=ac(b+1/c)+1/b=acp+1/b=(abcp+1)/b$. similarly we can show that $abc+p=(abcp+1)/a$, and next $abc+p=(abcp+1)/c$ Since since $a,b,c$ are all distinct  so the LHS of  these eqs. wiill be equal to each other only if thse are zero. Hence $abc+p=0$, option (2) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve for all possible $(p,a,b,c)\in\mathbb{C}^4$ (not requiring that $a$, $b$, and $c$ be distinct, nor real).  This is a long solution, but maybe there is a simpler way to deal with the problem.

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ be such that there exists $p\in\mathbb{C}$ for which
$$pb=ab+1\,,$$
$$pc=bc+1\,,$$
and $$pa=ca+1\,.$$  Write $x:=a+b+c$, $y:=bc+ca+ab$, and $z:=abc$. Adding all three equations above yields
$$px=y+3\,.\tag{1}$$
Observe that
$$pbc=abc+c\,,$$
$$pca=abc+a\,,$$
and
$$pab=abc+b\,.$$
Adding these three equation leads to
$$py=3z+x\,.\tag{2}$$
Finally, we also have
$$pabc=a^2bc+ca=az+ca\,,$$
$$pabc=ab^2c+ab=bz+ab\,,$$
and
$$pabc=abc^2+bc=cz+bc\,.$$
Sum these three equations to get
$$3pz=xz+y\,.\tag{3}$$
From (1) and (2),
$$y(y+3)=pxy=x(3z+x)\,.\tag{*}$$
From (1) and (3),
$$3z(y+3)=3pxz=x(xz+y)\,.\tag{#}$$

If $x=0$, then $y=-3$ by (1).  Hence, (2) implies $z=-p$.    Then, (3) gives $$-3p^2=3pz=xz+y=-3$$ or $p=\pm1$.  That is, $$(p,x,y,z)=(\pm1,0,-3,\mp1)\,.$$

If $x\neq 0$ and $y=0$, then $x=-3z$ by (2).   Using (1), we get $px=3$ or $pz=-1$.  By (3), we see that $$-3=3pz=xz=-3z^2$$
or $z=\pm 1$.  That is, $$(p,x,y,z)=(\pm1,\pm3,0,\mp1)\,.$$

If $x\neq 0$ and $y=-3$, then (1) shows that $p=0$.  Thus, (2) gives $x=-3z$, and (3) gives $$0=3pz=xz+y=-3z^2-3\,.$$
That is, $z=\pm\text{i}$.  This means
$$(p,x,y,z)=(0,\pm3\text{i},-3,\mp\text{i})\,.$$

Suppose now that $x\neq 0$ and $y\notin\{-3,0\}$.  Using (*) and (#), we have
$$x(3z+x)\cdot3z(y+3)=y(y+3)\cdot x(xz+y)\,.$$
As $x\neq 0$ amd $y\neq -3$, we obtain
$$3z(3z+x)=y(xz+y)\text{ or }z(y-3)x=-(y-3z)(y+3z)\,.$$
If $y=3$, then $y-3z=0$ or $y+3z=0$, which gives $z=\pm 1$.  That is, $$(p,x,y,z)\in\big\{(2,3,3,1), (-1,-6,3,1), (1,6,3,-1),(-2,-3,3,-1)\big\}\,.$$
If $y\neq 3$, then $$x=-\frac{(y-3z)(y+3z)}{z(y-3)}\,,$$
where we note that $z\neq 0$.

Plug this into (*) to get
$$y(y+3)=-\frac{(y-3z)(y+3z)}{z(y-3)}\,\left(3z-\frac{(y-3z)(y+3z)}{z(y-3)}\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$y(y+3)=\frac{y(y-3z)(y+3z)(y-3z^2)}{z^2(y-3)^2}\,.$$
Because $y\neq 0$, we obtain
$$z^2(y-3)^2(y+3)=(y-3z)(y+3z)(y-3z^2)\,.$$
This is equivalent to
$$(z-1)(z+1)(y^3-27z^2)=0\,.$$
If $z=-1$, then we obtain the family
$$(p,x,y,z)=(+1,t,-3-t,-1)\,,$$
where $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,\pm3\}$.  If $z=-1$, then we obtain the family
$$(p,x,y,z)=(-1,t,-3+t,+1)\,,$$
where $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,\pm3\}$.  If $y^3=27z^2$, then we obtain the family
$$(p,x,y,z)=\left(t+\frac{1}{t},3t,3t^2,t^3\right)$$
for $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0,\dfrac{\pm1\pm\sqrt{3}\text{i}}{2},\pm1\right\}$.

In conclusion, all possible $(p,x,y,z)\in\mathbb{C}^4$ are

1. $(+1,t,-3-t,-1)$ with $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{\dfrac{+3\pm3\sqrt{3}\text{i}}{2}\right\}$,
2. $(-1,t,-3+t,+1)$ with $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{\dfrac{-3\pm3\sqrt{3}\text{i}}{2}\right\}$, and
3. $\left(t+\dfrac{1}{t},3t,3t^2,t^3\right)$ with $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Note that in the third case, we obtain $$(p,x,y,z,a,b,c)=\left(t+\dfrac{1}{t},3t,3t^2,t^3,t,t,t\right)\text{ where }t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\,.$$
If we demand that $a$, $b$, and $c$ be distinct, then the only possibilities are the first two cases, where $p=-z=-abc$.

The first two cases yield pairwise distinct values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.  Therefore, the solutions to the original problem are
$$(p,x,y,z,a,b,c)=(s,st,t-3,-s,s\alpha_t,s\beta_t,s\gamma_t)$$ with $s\in\{\pm1\}$ and $t\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{\dfrac{3\pm3\sqrt{3}\text{i}}{2}\right\}$,
where $\alpha_t,\beta_t,\gamma_t$ are the roots of the polynomial $$Q_t(u):=u^3-tu^2+(t-3)u+1\,.$$  The discriminant of $Q_t(u)$ is 
$$D(t):=t^4-6t^3+27t^2-54t+81\,,$$ and we have  $$D(t)=\left(t^2-3t+9\right)^2=\left(\left(t-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\frac{27}{4}\right)^2>0$$
for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  Hence, when $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we are guaranteed that $\alpha_t,\beta_t,\gamma_t$ are three distinct real numbers.  (Indeed, the four complex roots of $D(t)$ are $\dfrac{3\pm3\sqrt{3}\text{i}}{2}$, each with multiplicity $2$, and so $Q_t(u)$ has no repeated roots when $t$ is not a root of $D(t)$.)

Comment: I think you’ve introduced too many dead cases by unrestricting $a,b,c$.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog  I have no interest solving just the given problem.  I wanted to see all possible solutions, regardless of whether $a$, $b$, and $c$ are distinct or not.