$a, b, c,d$ are real numbers with different values, $a+\frac{1}{b}=b+\frac{1}{c}=c+\frac{1}{d}=d+\frac{1}{a}=x$, find value of $x$.
This is the question I encountered in my Maths Olympiad book, and I found it difficult to solve. See the question below:

(Shanghai Mathematics Olympiad Competition) If $a, b, c,d$ are all real numbers with different values, and $a+\frac{1}{b}=b+\frac{1}{c}=c+\frac{1}{d}=d+\frac{1}{a}=x$, find the value of $x$.
(Answer for this question: $x= \pm \sqrt{2}$)

I know that we have $5$ unknown, which are $a, b, c, d $ and $x$, but we only can form $4$ equations.
As $a, b, c, d$ are all distinct, so the all the values of $a-b$, $b-c$, $c-d$, $a-d$ can’t be $0.$

I can’t reach to the answer for this question, so I need some help. Here’s my working:
$$a+\frac{1}{b}=b+\frac{1}{c} \implies \frac{ac-1}{c}=\frac{b^2-1}{b}~~~~~(1)$$
$$b+\frac{1}{c}=c+\frac{1}{d} \implies \frac{bd-1}{d}=\frac{c^2-1}{c}~~~~~(2)$$
$$c+\frac{1}{d}=d+\frac{1}{a} \implies \frac{ca-1}{a}=\frac{d^2-1}{d}~~~~~(3)$$
$$a+\frac{1}{b}=d+\frac{1}{a} \implies \frac{db-1}{b}=\frac{a^2-1}{a}~~~~~(4)$$
$(1) \div (3)$,
$$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{d(b-1)(b+1)}{b(d-1)(d+1)} ~~~~~(5)$$
$(2) \div (4)$,
$$\frac{b}{d}=\frac{a(c-1)(c+1)}{c(a+1)(a-1)}~~~~~(6)$$
$(5) \times (6)$,
$$\frac{a^2(c-1)(c+1)}{c^2(a-1)(a+1)}=\frac{(b-1)(b+1)}{(d-1)(d+1)}$$
From here, I can’t sure that if my working is helpful to solve this question or not? If not, how to solve this question?

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61054/if-a-frac1b-b-frac1c-c-frac1a-for-distinct-a-b-c-how-to-find-the-v

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the unanswered $x+\frac{1}{y}=y+\frac{1}{z}=z+\frac{1}{w}=w+\frac{1}{x}=t$, find $t$, plus the AoPS thread Algebra (that I reference in my answer) and also Hard algebra unsolved. In addition, there's the similar AoPS thread Value of x^4.

Sorry, I forgot to fill in the Approach0 search URL in my comment above. FYI, it's this.

@JohnOmielan Thanks for sharing this search URL.

The following is basically what's done by Farenhajt in Post #$3$ of the AoPS thread Algebra. First, we get
$$a + \frac{1}{b} = x \;\;\to\;\; b = \frac{1}{x - a} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Next, there's
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
b + \frac{1}{c} & = x \\
\frac{1}{x - a} + \frac{1}{c} & = x \\
\frac{c + x - a}{(x - a)c} & = x \\
x + c - a & = cx(x - a)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Similar to \eqref{eq1A}, we have
$$c + \frac{1}{d} = x \;\;\to\;\; d = \frac{1}{x - c} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Also, as was done in \eqref{eq2A}, there's
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
d + \frac{1}{a} & = x \\
\frac{1}{x - c} + \frac{1}{a} & = x \\
\frac{a + x - c}{(x - c)a} & = x \\
x + a - c & = ax(x - c)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Subtracting \eqref{eq2A} from \eqref{eq4A}, and using that $a \neq c \;\to\; a - c \neq 0$, gives that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(x + (a - c)) - (x - (a - c) & = (ax^2 - ac) - (cx^2 - ac) \\
2(a - c) & = x^2(a - c) \\
(x^2 - 2)(a - c) & = 0 \\
x^2 - 2 & = 0 \\
x & = \pm \sqrt{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

I noticed an interesting pattern in the system of equation that helps solve it rather nicely.
The equations can be rewritten as:$$(1)\:a = x - b^{-1}\\
(2)\:b = x - c^{-1}\\
(3)\:c = x - d^{-1}\\
(4)\:d = x - a^{-1}$$
The if can take $x - a^{-1}$ as $d$ and put it in the equation $(3)$, then we put c in the equation $(2)$ and lastly b in the equation $(1$). This leaves us with the following monstrous equation:
$$a = x-(x-(x-(x-a^{-1})^{-1})^{-1})^{-1}$$ or:
$$\LARGE a=x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{a}}}}$$
We can then proceed to simplify this expression and we get:
$$a^{2}x^{3} - ax^{2} - 2a^{2}x + a = ax^{4} - x^{3} - 3ax^{2} + 2x + a\\
- ax^{4} + a^{2}x^{3} + x^{3} + 2ax^{2} - 2a^{2}x - 2x = 0  \\
x(- ax^{3} + a^{2}x^{2} + x^{2} + 2ax - 2a^{2} - 2) = 0\\
x(x^{2}(a^{2}-ax+1)-2(a^{2}-ax+1)) = 0\\
x(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})(a^{2}-ax+1) = 0$$
So we receive the roots $\pm\sqrt{2}$. And interestingly $0$ appears to be the third root, I believe the adjustment of the expressions does not limit $x$ to non-zero value. Edit: zero cannot be a root because the values of $a, b, c, d$ have to be different, otherwise it would be a solution as well.
This may not be the fastest approach as it requires quite a bit of algebra but I still think it's a curious way of solving this :)

There is a subtle shortcut. When you derive the cubic equation for $x$, you may render $x=a+(1/a)$ as a sure (but extraneous) root because the equalities would be solved if we had allowed $a=b=c=d$. Dividing out the corresponding factor $ax-(a^2+1)$ then leaves $x^2-2=0$ for roots where the $a,b,c,d$ are distinct.

Sometimes you just have to know which rocks to look under.*
Compare the terms containing $a$ and isolate that variable from the others, without immediately attempting to solve for $a$. This yields
$a-\dfrac1{a}=d-b\tag{1}$
Similarly
$b-\dfrac1{b}=a-c\tag{2}$
$c-\dfrac1{c}=b-d\tag{3}$
$d-\dfrac1{d}=c-a\tag{4}$
Then from (1) and (3) we render
$c-\dfrac1{c}=-\left(a-\dfrac{1}{a}\right)$
If we convert this to a quadratic equation for $c$ we find two roots, which are described here in set notation. Equations (2) and (4) lead to the corresponding relation between $d$ and $b$:
$c\in\{-a,(1/a)\}, d\in\{-b,(1/b)\}\tag{5}$
Suppose we select $c=-a,b=-d$ from the above. Then
$a+\dfrac{1}{b}=b-\dfrac{1}{a}=-a-\dfrac{1}{b}=-b+\dfrac{1}{a}$
This is contradictory because it implies $a=-(1/a)$, which has no real solutions. So if we were to select $c=-a$ it would imply $d=(1/b)$. Likewise $c=(1/a)$ implies $d=-b$.
We have one more possibility: using both reciprocal relations in (5). This gives
$a+\dfrac{1}{b}=b+a=...$
and this is immediately contradictory because it implies $b=\pm1$ and then $d=1/b=b$.
So we have two candidates from (5):
$c=-a,d=(1/b)$
$c=(1/a),d=-b$
These are cyclic permutatiobs of each othercand $a,b,c,d$ enter symmetrically, so either candidate alone will yield tge entire solution set for $x$. We choose the first candidate above and then
$a+\dfrac{1}{b}=b-\dfrac{1}{a}=-a+b=\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{a}$
So $a=(1/a)$ and thus either $a=1$ or $a=-1$, with $c$ being the additive inverse.
Suppose we select $a=1,c=-1$. Then Eq. (2) above becomes
$b-\dfrac1{b}=2,$
from which $b=1\pm\sqrt2$. Then with $a=1$ we get
$x=1+\dfrac{1}{1\pm\sqrt2}=\pm\sqrt2$
This matches the given answer. The reader may verify that the same roots for $x$ would be obtained using $a=-1,c=1$ combined with $c=-a,d=(1/b)$, or by using $c=(1/a),d=-b$.
*And sometimes you just have to end a sentence with a preposition.
