# Find a polynomial from an equality

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

Find all polynomials for which

What I have done so far:
for $x=8$ we get $p(8)=0$
for $x=1$ we get $p(2)=0$

So there exists a polynomial $p(x) = (x-2)(x-8)q(x)$

This is where I get stuck. How do I continue?

**UPDATE**

After substituting and simplifying I get
$(x-4)(2ax+b)=4(x-2)(ax+b)$

For $x = 2,8$ I get

$x= 2 \to -8a+b=0$

$x= 8 \to 32a+5b=0$

which gives $a$ and $b$ equal to zero.

Comment: I can substitute $p(x) = (x-1)(x-8)q(x)$ into the equality given at the first line but I don't know how that would help.

Comment: You probably mean $p(x)=(x-2)(x-8)q(x)$.

Comment: Yes @drhab thank you for spotting that!

Comment: what is $q(x)$?

Comment: q(x) is just a random polynomial

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/find-polynomials-such-that-x-16p2x-16x-1px/4150#4150

Comment: Why did you edit your question and delete off the formula?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The route you take is fruitful.

$p\left(x\right)=\left(x-2\right)\left(x-8\right)q\left(x\right)$
leads to:

$$\left(x-4\right)q\left(2x\right)=2\left(x-2\right)q\left(x\right)$$

Then $4$ must be a root of $q$, so $q\left(x\right)=\left(x-4\right)r\left(x\right)$ leading to:

$$r\left(2x\right)=r\left(x\right)$$

Then $r\left(x\right)$ must be a constant polynomial and we end up with: $$p\left(x\right)=c\left(x-2\right)\left(x-4\right)\left(x-8\right)$$

Comment: I don't get how $r(2x)=r(x)$. Could you show how you got here?

Comment: Substituting $q\left(x\right)=\left(x-4\right)r\left(x\right)$ in
$\left(x-4\right)q\left(2x\right)=2\left(x-2\right)q\left(x\right)$
gives $(x-4)(2x-4)r(2x)=2(x-2)(x-4)r(x)$ hence $r(2x)=r(x)$

Comment: You very welcome and I am glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Let the highest of power of $x$ be $n$

So, $(x-8)[a(2x)^n+\cdots]=8(x-1)[ax^n+\cdots]$

Comparing the coefficients of $x^{n+1},$
 $$a2^n=8a\implies n=3$$

Let $p(x)=(x-2)(x-8)(ax+b)$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants to be determined

Hope you take it from here?

Comment: Have you forgotten something after $x^{n+1}$?

Comment: I will give it a try! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Nash, I just needed to find the coefficients of  the highest power(n+1) of $x$, which can not be contributed by the lower terms, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. I am trying to do that too but so far no luck

Comment: @Nash, So, we have $$(x-8)(2x-1)(2x-8)(2ax+b)=8(x-1)(x-1)(ax+b)$$  Set $x=8, 1$ one by one

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x=2,8$ I had made a mistake before if you look above at my question.

Comment: @Nash,I was somehow de-focused in search the highest power. Thanks

Comment: @Nash, If $p(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(ax+b),$ $$(x-8)p(2x)=8(x-1)p(x)$$ leaves $x(4a+b)=0\iff b=-4a$ provided my calculations are right

Comment: @Nash, Please update your answer with your effort

Answer (score 2):

The following is essentially @drhab's solution, but uses only one idea repeatedly.

From $$ (x-8)p(2x) = 8(x-1)p(x) $$ we see $x-8$ divides $p(x)$.  Let $p(x) = (x-8)p_1(x)$ and substitute, yielding $$ 2(x-8)(x-4)p_1(2x) = 8(x-1)(x-8)p_1(x) $$
From this we see $x-4$ divides $p_1(x)$.  Let $p_1(x) = (x-4)p_2(x)$ and substitute, yielding $$ 4(x-8)(x-4)(x-2)p_2(2x) = 8(x-1)(x-4)(x-8)p_2(x) $$
From this we see $x-2$ divides $p_2(x)$.  Let $p_2(x) = (x-2)p_3(x)$ and substitute, yielding $$ 8(x-8)(x-4)(x-2)(x-1)p_3(2x) = 8(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)(x-8)p_3(x) $$
( ... and our recursive process stops because the new $x-1$ factor divides the $x-1$ that's been lingering on the right all along.)
But now we simplify to $p_3(2x) = p_3(x)$ and the rest of @drhab's argument finishes the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Following the method outlined in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888/find-polynomials-such-that-x-16p2x-16x-1px/4150#4150) we can write the original equation in the form
$$\frac{\sigma p}{p} = \frac{\sigma^3 r}{r}$$
where $\sigma p(x) = p(2x)$ and $r(x)=8-x$. Using the "additive notation" (see the referenced post) we obtain
$$p=\frac{\sigma^3-1}{\sigma-1}r=(\sigma^2+\sigma+1)r=(4x-8)(2x-8)(x-8)$$ unique up to a constant factor.